# problem with concating hash code to single string _ Java Script

Tags: javascript

I have this array :

```
let a = ["a", "www", "qwqwq"];
```

and I need to iterate in it for getting the hash of every single element. and store it in single variable as a string.

```
function hashCode(str) {
    var hash = 0;
    if (str.length == 0) return hash;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        char = str.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = (hash << 5) - hash + char;
        hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    return hash;
}
let strHash = "";
for (b of a){
    strHash.concat(`${hashCode(b)}`)
}
console.log(strHash)
```

but I get empty string. why?

Comment: `let strHash = a.map(hashCode).join('')` would be a terser way to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`concat` return a new string, you need to change your code to:

```
for (b of a){
   strHash = strHash.concat(`${hashCode(b)}`)
}
```

Or, if you want a more functional approach you could do:

```
const strHash = a.map(hashCode).join("")
```

Comment: Here is the doc of the concat() method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```js
let a = ["a", "www", "qwqwq"];

function hashCode(str) {
    var hash = 0;
    if (str.length == 0) return hash;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        const char = str.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = (hash << 5) - hash + char;
        hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    return hash;
}
let strHash = [];
for (const b of a) {
    strHash.push(hashCode(b));
}
console.log(strHash.join("")) // 97118167108015397
```

OR this solution:

```js
let strHash = "";
for (const b of a) {
    strHash += hashCode(b);
}
console.log(strHash) // 97118167108015397
```

NOTE: Your code has some javascript issues such as you didn't write `var/let/const` keyword before your variables in lines 6, 7, 14